# Bound probability of deviation of norm

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For $X, Y$ iid, show that:
$$P(||X|| > t) \leq 3 P(||X + Y|| >2t/3)$$
for any norm $||\cdot||$ and $t >0$

The proof I've seen is just two steps, but I am not understanding the argument leading to the inequality:
$$P(||X|| > t) = P(||(X + Y) + (X + Z) - (Y + Z)|| > 2t) \leq 3 P(||X + Y|| >2t/3)$$
where $Z$ is also distributed as $X$ and $Y$ and independent of them.

This seems like an application of the triangle inequality, but I haven't been able to get the details right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality follows from the identity $2X=(X+Y)+(X+Z)-(Y+Z)$. The inequality follows from the following: If $$\|X+Y\| \leq \frac  {2t} 3$$, $$\|X+Z\| \leq \frac  {2t} 3$$ and $$\|Y+Z\| \leq \frac  {2t} 3$$ then $$\|(X+Y)+(X+Z)-(Y+Z)\| \leq \frac {2t} 3++\frac {2t} 3+\frac {2t} 3= 2t$$ which gives $(\|(X+Y)+(X+Z)-(Y+Z)\| > 2t) \subseteq (\|X+Y\| > \frac  {2t} 3) \cup (\|X+Z\| > \frac  {2t} 3) \cup (\|Y+Z\| > \frac  {2t} 3)$